# Use Spring to run Flyway migration before starting webapp

Tags: spring, flyway

We use Spring and are integrating Flyway in a webapp that uses DispatcherServlet and runs a background DB thread.

How do control the execution flow of Spring so the migration happens *before* it fires up? Delaying DispatcherServlet start and Controller creation should be enough for our purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you really want is for Flyway to migrate the database before your persistence layer comes up.

Since your controllers already depend this persistence layer, you now need to make the persistence layer itself depend on Flyway. Using XML configuration, this can be achieved using a depends-on attribute as described in the [official docs](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/#spring).

Comment: I'm not a Spring expert, but I was looking at dependsOn to do this. Actually, I'd like the persistence layer to be available while migrating.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Spring Boot flyway support http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html

I havent used it, but I hope it run the flyway scripts before it "starts" the "real" application. (If not it would be quite useless)

Answer (score 0):

I think afterMigrate method of [Flyway Callbacks](http://flywaydb.org/documentation/callbacks.html) are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could have flyway in a separate factory to your spring MVC stuff. That way you can force the factory with flyway and other business logic etc to be completely created and done before the specifically MVC stuff comes up.

I would recommend you separate these two concerns in to separate factories in any case as it separates the two contexts quite nicely.

One way to achieve this is to start the business logic/flyway factory with a listener that is before the spring MVC stuff...